# Why is octaoxygen diamagnetic?

Tags: electromagnetism, orbitals, quantum-chemistry

I tried considering that according to LCAO-MO theory $O_2$ is paramagnetic, which is confirmed by experimental evidence. Since octaoxygen has the crystal structure in figure, I thought there is a kind of overlapping of the molecular orbitals $\pi^{\ast}$  of each $O_2$ with the others so that the unpaired electrons of one molecule pair with the unpaired electrons of the adjacent molecule, one by one.

I realise this is only an intuitive answer, but I am not much acquainted with quantum mechanics and applied group theory.

[image]
[image]

Comment: My apologies.. I deleted my answer, as that was based on totally misunderstood concept. I think I have to think about it again..

Comment: This same question has been asked in [chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/163209/why-is-octaoxygen-diamagnetic).